# Galois extension over a field of characteristic $0$ of order $2^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Assume that $E$ is Galois over a field $F$ of characteristic 0 and $Gal(E/F)$ is a group of order $2^n$. Prove that $E$ can be obtained from $F$ by a sequence of simple extensions by roots of polynomials of the form $x^2 - c$

A group of order $2^n$ is nilpotent and a polynomial is irreducible iff $c$ is a non square.  Does extensions of the form $x^2 -c$ mean extensions by the root?

Comment: There is no field of characteristic $2^n$ here. Only an extension of order $2^n$.

Comment: Yes, by the root. Or, equivalently, as a quotient of the polynomial ring by the ideal generated by it.

Comment: @arthur so is the extension nilpotent?  I was given a hint to use a theorem that says that.  Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: There must be other conditions on the field: you'll not succeed over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician so can you give me a hint on how to proceed?  I've been stuck for hours

Comment: Your title is extremely confusing, and the situation is not improved by your choice not to state the problem precisely in the body of your question. For the title, perhaps you meant something like: “Degree $2^n$ Galois extensions of a field of characteristic $0$.”

Comment: @Lubin Sorry I'm new to asking questions.  I fixed it so please let me know what you think?

Comment: You have completely  changed the question since my comment. There's a good text-book answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $\neq 2.$

We say $L/F$ is a *quadratic extension* if $L\cong F[X]/(X^2-c)$ for some $c \in F.$

We say $M/F$ is a *quadratic tower* if there exists chain of intermediate fields
$$F=F_0\subseteq F_1 \subseteq \ldots \subseteq F_n=M$$
such that $F_i/F_{i-1}$ is a quadratic extension for each $i=1,\ldots,n.$

**Claim.** Every non-trivial Galois extension of $F$ whose degree is a power of $2$ is a quadratic tower.

*Proof.* We proceed by induction.

---

*(Base case).* Suppose $K/F$ is a Galois extension with $[K:F]=2.$

Choose $\alpha \in K$ such that $\alpha \notin F$ (we can do this since $[K:F]=2$ and so $K\neq F$).

Then $\alpha$ has minimal polynomial over $F$ of the form $X^2+aX+b$ for some $a,b \in F.$

Take $\beta = \alpha+\frac{1}{2}a \in K\,$ and $c=\frac{1}{4}a^2-b \in F$ (we can divide by 2 and by 4 since char$(F)\neq 2$).

Then $\beta \notin F$ (because $\alpha \notin F$) and $\beta$ is a root of $X^2-c.$

Hence $\beta$ has degree $2$ over $F$ and so we must have $K=F(\beta)\cong F[X]/(X^2-c).$

---

*(Induction step).* Suppose that the claim is true for all Galois extensions of $F$ of degree $2^m.$

Let $E/F$ be a Galois extension with $[E:F]=2^{m+1}.$

Since Gal$(E/F)$ is a finite $p$-group (with $p=2,$ of course), it has a subgroup of size $2^m$.

So by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, we have an intermediate field
$$F\subseteq K \subseteq E$$
such that $E/K$ is Galois with $[E:K]=2^m.$

Hence, by induction hypothesis, $E/K$ is a quadratic tower.

Also, since $[K:F]=2,$ we see that $K/F$ is a quadratic extension (by the base case).

Therefore $E/F$ is a quadratic tower and the claim follows by induction.